# Problem with breqn

Tags: errors, breqn

The minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sigma_n(z) = \sum_{ k = 0 }^{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor } (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{2k} a(z)^{n - 2k}\, b(z)^{2 k}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This leads to an error:

"Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

Removing the package 'breqn' solves the problem.

Any workaround?

Comment: I think it is a bug and I made a bug report: https://github.com/wspr/breqn/issues/42